# Seamless PDF note taking between iPad Pro and MacOS?

Tags: mac, ipad, pdf

When viewing a PDF file, is there a way to take notes on it on my iPad Pro (highlight, write, etc) and then have it seamlessly transfer to my MacBook Air where I can take notes as well?

The ideal way would be like Notes work seamlessly between an iPad Pro and a Mac.

Searching for [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=iPad%20mac%20seamless%20pdf%20editing&) question yields [no result](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=iPad%20mac%20seamless%20pdf%20editing&) because there are other things done with PDF and done seamless that take up the search results. Furthermore there is nothing about this question specifically.

Again, I am asking to create notes (highlight, write, etc) of **PDF documents** *specifically*. I am not looking for taking notes in general, I want to read my PDF files and mark them. After they are marked and edited on my iPad I want the changes to show up (within seconds and without me having to press "send") on my MacBook.

I have the latest and greatest update to both my devices.

Comment: It's rather easy to overlook the (single) instance of the word PDF in the title. I've edited your question to make that clearer. Please do not make insinuations like in your last comment; see the [Code of Conduct](/conduct).

Comment: Continuity Markup in iOS 13, iPadOS and macOS Catalina 10.15 or later lets you annotate documents on your Mac using your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch. Wich version of each OS are you running on your devices?

Comment: @slartibartfast latest, so Big Sur and ios 14.7.1. However its specifically PDF. Does it let you annotate PDF documents?

Comment: Apple calls it [Continuity Sketch & Continuity Markup](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204975)

Comment: @slartibartfast it says it works for apps supporting it but there are no apps, besides iBooks, that opens PDF on iPad that is offered by Apple themselves.

Comment: PDFs can be opened and annotated directly in Apple’s Files or as you wrote Books. Continuity Markup works from both with Preview on the Mac.

Comment: @slartibartfast I managed to solve it! Continuity Markup does not work from Preview nor Books. However it works in Quick Look (Right click the PDF). Then you press "annote" and then you connect your MacBook using BlueTooth TM to the iPad!

Answer (score 1):

Continuity Markup is one solution. I have not found a way to use it in anything *besides* Quick Look. Quick Look can be accessed by right clicking a PDF file. Then click "annote" and then connect your MacBook to your iPad via BlueTooth. Then a new icon will appear that you can press and a new app will open on your iPad. All editing is seamless between the iPad and the Mac OS!